# How to make node throw an error for UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, promise, nock

I'm using `nock.back` to mock out some API calls. When unexpected calls are made, `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` gets printed to the console, but my tests pass, and those warnings are easily missed in the rest of the console output. I want an exception thrown instead of a silent error. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I use promises is:

```
function myFunction(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) -> {
       try {
           // Logic
           resolve(logic)
       } catch(e) {
           reject('Provide your error message here -> ' + e)
       }
   })
}
```

Or !

```
function myFunction().then( // Calls the function defined previously
    logic => { // Instead of logic you can write any other suitable variable name for success
        console.log('Success case')     
    }, 
    error => {
        console.log('myFunction() returned an error: ' + error)
    }
)
```

---

UPD

Have you had a look here? https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection 
It describes an unhandledRejection event being emitted when you have no catch for a rejection from a Promise and provides the code to catch the WARNING and output it nicely to console.

(copy paste)

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
   console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', p, 'reason:', reason);
   // application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});
```

Node.js runs on a single process.

Comment: I know this is best practice, but I want my tests to fail when that best practice isn't being followed.

Comment: Have you had a look here? https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection It describes an unhandledRejection event that happens when you do not catch a rejection from a Promise and gives you the code to basically catch the WARNING.

Comment: That first snippet is useless, you don't need a `try`/`catch` inside the Promise constructor callback

Comment: This is close enough for now, I added `process.exit(1)` in the handler so the tests won't pass.